# How to get list of directory containing images in android

Tags: android, android-file, subdirectory

I have used following code to get list of directories

```
String ROOT_DIR = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
```

ROOT_DIR is passed is as string

```
public static ArrayList<String> getDirectoryPaths(String directory) {
        ArrayList<String> pathArray = new ArrayList<>();
        File file = new File(directory);
        File[] listfiles = file.listFiles();
        if (listfiles != null) {

            for (int i = 0; i < listfiles.length; i++) {
                if (listfiles[i].isDirectory()) {
                    pathArray.add(listfiles[i].getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }

        }
        return pathArray;
    }
```

`

It returns all directories path but i want to get the path of the directories containing images only like it shows in gallery Eg (Camera, WhatsAppImages, hike,...); I want to get path of all of them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

Create a Bucket Class

```
public class Bucket {

    private String name;
    private String firstImageContainedPath;

    public Bucket(String name, String firstImageContainedPath) {
        this.name = name;
        this.firstImageContainedPath = firstImageContainedPath;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getFirstImageContainedPath() {
        return firstImageContainedPath;
    }
}
```

Then, Add this method, it is going to return all the buckets where there are Images.

```
    public static List<Bucket> getImageBuckets(Context mContext){
            List<Bucket> buckets = new ArrayList<>();
            Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            String [] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            if(cursor != null){
                File file;
                while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                    String bucketPath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]));
String fisrtImage = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[1]));
                    file = new File(fisrtImage);
                if (file.exists() && !bucketSet.contains(bucketName)) {
                    buckets.add(new Bucket(bucketName, fisrtImage));
                }
                }
                cursor.close();
            }
            return buckets;
        }
```

Finally, create your custom spinner item and fill your spinner with an adapter.

Next Step is to fill the gridview with images from the selected bucket.
This method is going to return all the images according the bucketpath.

```
public List<String> getImagesByBucket(@NonNull String bucketPath){

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String [] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        String selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME+" =?";
        String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED+" DESC";

        List<String> images = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection,new String[]{bucketPath}, orderBy);

        if(cursor != null){
            File file;
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]));
                file = new File(path);
                if (file.exists() && !images.contains(path)) {
                    images.add(path);
                }
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        return images;
    }
```

Finally, create your adapter and fill your gridview.

I hope, It can help you.

Comment: I want to create a grid view and spinner like insatgram in which when we select directories it shows all images there.how to do with this code

Comment: hmm, I see. Firstly, you should get the list of the buckets or folder where there are images to show them the spinner( first photo and bucket name). Then, you when you select a folder, the gridview should show all the images in the folder. Wait me a time to change the answer.

Comment: Thanks it is now loading images in grid view perfectly

Comment: Thanks it is now loading images in grid view perfectly but i problem is that it loads less images then there are in that folder means suppose there are 45 images in camera but it loads 40 of them and this count changes every time it is selected is there any error in adapter can you help me in this  here is my code :---
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_TRi8_oI7SJdzllcDdpSF8tbWc

Comment: can you suggest any solution

Comment: Sure bro, but I'm travelling now, I hope you can wait me 1 day more.

Comment: Hi, firstly, check how many images you are getting from the bucket on the File FileSearch method getImagesByBucket  "Log.v("FileSearch","images = "+images.size());" . Is the size of the array the same with the real amount of images?.

Comment: Yes,the size returned is same as the original no of images in particular directories..but all images are not loaded in grid view...

Comment: Question. why are you adding Camera and pictures folders manually on your list of directories?.  FilePaths filePaths = new FilePaths();
        directories = FileSearch.getImageBuckets(getActivity());
        directories.add(filePaths.CAMERA);
        directories.add(filePaths.PICTURES);

Comment: Oh that I was trying to do manually before asking question and forgot to   remove it...

Comment: Cool. I think the problem is the implementación of your arrayadapter. Could you change you adapter to BaseAdapter?

Comment: What changes would be needed if I use base adapter?

Comment: Your arrayadapter implementation looks quit messy and similar to BaseAdapter, for that reason just tell you to try BaseAdapter to manage the list by yourself.

Comment: Becareful about this answer. It will return you ALL the records. When maybe just what you wanted was the bucket names.